# Сдвиг элемента массива.Алгоритм Хэмминга

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Ребят, если не большой вопрос.
Делаю алгоритм корректирующего кода Хэмминга,на вход ввожу данные

string encod = "1100011011100111000000010111010010000100010110101010001";

char[] data = encod.ToCharArray();

В алгоритме каждый раз на вход должны идти новые 4 символа, но у меня всегда берется первые 4 символа "1100", а остальные игнорирует. Посдкажите как сделать, чтобы у меня проходило по всем элементам, а не только по 4 первым

```
Console.WriteLine("\nEncoded data ");
    for (int b = 0; b < data.Length; b += 4)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                encoded[i] += ((data[j] - 0) * (gmatrix[j, i] - 0));
            encoded[i] = encoded[i] % 2;
            Console.Write("{0} |", encoded[i]);

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

---

Вот весь код моей программы. Кодировка слова, которое напишешь идет за счет Шеннона-фано, а после добавляю в Хэмминг. Но тут у меня в программе берет только 4 символа (пример 1100) а остальные отбрасывает .... Вот я и хочу чтобы все по 4 сымвола прошлись.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


class A
{
double[] P1 = { 0.122, 0.090, 0.074, 0.059, 0.055, 0.053, 0.047, 0.044, 0.041, 0.040, 
0.034, 0.034, 0.032, 0.032, 0.026, 0.026, 0.023, 0.021, 0.018, 0.017, 0.016, 0.015, 
0.013, 0.012, 0.010, 0.008, 0.008, 0.007, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.003, 0.002 };
char[] Alpha ={'','о','а','и','?','н','в','т','е','р',
'с','л','к','у','д','п','м','ь','з','й','б','я','г','ч','ш',
'х','щ','ж','ц','ю','ї','є','ф'};
string[] Res = new string[33];
double schet1 = 0;
double schet2 = 0;
public void Sort()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < P1.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < P1.Length - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (P1[j] < P1[j + 1])
            {
                char temp2;
                double temp1 = 0;
                temp1 = P1[j];
                temp2 = Alpha[j];
                P1[j] = P1[j + 1];
                Alpha[j] = Alpha[j + 1];
                P1[j + 1] = temp1;
                Alpha[j + 1] = temp2;
            }
        }
    }
}
int m;
public int Delenie_Posledovatelnosty(int L, int R)
{
    schet1 = 0;
    for (int i = L; i <= R - 1; i++)
    {
        schet1 = schet1 + P1[i];
    }
    schet2 = P1[R];
    m = R;
    while (schet1 >= schet2)
    {
        m = m - 1;
        schet1 = schet1 - P1[m];
        schet2 = schet2 + P1[m];
    }
    return m;
}
int g = 0;
public void Fano(int L, int R)
{
    int n;
    if (L < R)
    {
        n = Delenie_Posledovatelnosty(L, R);
        for (int i = L; i <= R; i++)
        {
            if (i <= n) Res[i] += Convert.ToByte(0);
            else Res[i] += Convert.ToByte(1);
        }
        Fano(L, n);
        Fano(n + 1, R);
    }
}
public static void Main()
{
    A ob = new A();
    ob.Sort();
    ob.Fano(0, 32);
    string name, encod = "";
    for (int w = 0; w < 32; w++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ob.Alpha[w] + " " + ob.Res[w]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Прiзвище та iм'я");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    char[] buff = name.ToCharArray();
    double n_ = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < buff.Length; y++)
    {
        for (int g = 0; g < 32; g++)
        {
            if (buff[y] == ob.Alpha[g])
            {
                encod += ob.Res[g];
                n_ += ob.P1[g] * ob.Res[g].Length;
            }
        }
    }

    int Ma = buff.Length;
    double k = 1;
    int n = 0;
    while (Ma > k)
    {
        k = Math.Pow(2, n);
        if (Ma <= k)
        {
            break;
        }
        n++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(encod);
    Console.WriteLine(n);
    Console.WriteLine("n| = " + n_);
    Console.WriteLine("ню = " + n / n_);

    // Хемминг начало 

    //char data = encod;
    char[] data = encod.ToCharArray();
    int[] encoded = new int[7];
    int[] edata = new int[7];
    int[] syndrome = new int[5];
    int[,] hmatrix = new int[3, 7]{{1,0,0,0,1,1,1},
            {0,1,0,1,0,1,1},
            {0,0,1,1,1,0,1}};

    char[,] gmatrix = new char[4, 7] { { '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' }, { '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0' }, { '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0' }, { '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1' } };
    int i, j;
    Console.Write("\nHamming code----- Encoding\n\nEnter 4 bit data : \n");
    for (int d = 0; d < data.Length; d++)
    {

    }
    //Console.Write("\nGenerator matrix enter\n");
    /* for(i=0;i<4;i++){
         for(j=0;j<7;j++){
             Console.Write("{0},{1}",i,j);
            gmatrix[i,j]=Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
     }
     */
    Console.Write("\nGenerator matrix\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} \t|", gmatrix[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nEncoded data ");

        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)


                    encoded[i] += ((data[j]) * (gmatrix[j, i] - 0));
                    encoded[i] = encoded[i] % 2;


            Console.Write("{0} |", encoded[i]);

        }

    Console.Write("\nHamming code----- Decoding\n\nEnter encoded bits as recieved : \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        edata[i] = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            syndrome[i] += (edata[j] * hmatrix[i, j]);
        syndrome[i] = syndrome[i] % 2;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        if ((syndrome[0] == hmatrix[0, j]) && (syndrome[1] == hmatrix[1, j]) && (syndrome[2] == hmatrix[2, j]))
            break;
    if (j == 7)
        Console.Write("\nError free\n");
    else
    {
        Console.Write("\nError recieved at bit number {0} of data\n", j + 1);
        edata[j] = 0;
        Console.Write("\nCorrect data should be : ");
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            if (edata[j] == 48)
                Console.Write("{0} |", 0);
            else if (edata[j] == 49)
                Console.Write("{0} |", 1);
            else
                Console.Write("{0} |", edata[j]);
    }

    // Хемминг конец

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

}

Comment: `data[j]` => `data[b+j]` и не забудьте проверку длины `data`, если длина вдруг окажется не кратна четырем.

Comment: Извините, что не смог понять, но как правильно задать тут кратность?  =>  if(data.Length %4)   ?

Comment: Встречный вопрос: входную строку формируете вы? Каким образом? Если это двоичное представление байтов полученное из байтов - ни чего делать надо, если произвольный набор битов - надо. А кратность N по отношению к K проверяется как везде - остаток от деления N на K, если 0 - N кратно K, иначе нет

Comment: Входная строка формируется при ввроде строки и уже шифруеться в нули и единицы.

Comment: значит на входе последовательность бит произвольной длины. Как ваш алгоритм должен обрабатывать последовательность c длиной < 4?

Comment: Хмм, наверно отбрасывать тогда лишнее

Comment: только не отбрасывать, а дополнять до необходимой длины нулями, если это произвольная цепочка бит. Так что проще всего брать не произвольную цепочку, а битовое представление массива байт, прочитанного, например, из файла или полученного из введенной строки текста. В целом, стоит еще немного почитать про данный алгоритм. А решение озвученной в вопросе проблемы уместилось в первом комментарии.

Comment: как-то так... Скинул код выше.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу на основной вопрос

> В алгоритме каждый раз на вход должны идти новые 4 символа, но у меня всегда берется первые 4 символа "1100", а остальные игнорирует. Посдкажите как сделать, чтобы у меня проходило по всем элементам, а не только по 4 первым

Опишу стандартный способ перебрать N элементов группами по K штук. Применение к вашей конкретной задаче останется за вами.

```
//пусть на входе строка
string inputStr = "0123456789";
//перебирать будем группами по 3 (три) символа
int groupSize = 3;

for(int i = 0; i < inputStr.Length; i += groupSize)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < groupSize && j + i < inputStr.Length; j++)
    {
        //что-то делаем с символом, я буду просто выводить
        //реальный индекс нужного символа вычисляется как сумма индексов внешнего и 
        //внутреннего циклов
        Console.Write(inputStr[i+j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Вывод:

> 012
>   345
>   678
>   9

Обратите особое внимание на условие во внутреннем цикле. Если длина входной последовательности не будет кратна длине группы, при простом условии `j < groupSize` произойдет выход за границу исходной последовательности. Для того чтобы этого избежать, нужно дополнительно проверять значение индекса, который будет реально использоваться - сумма индексов внешнего и внутреннего циклов.

---

Несколько советов общего плана:

1. Строку не обязательно превращать в массив символов если требуется **только читать** значения по индексу.
2. В матрицу вы вычисляете и храните в виде символов, при этом используете только как числа. Зачем эти лишние преобразования? Храните числа как числа.
3. Именование переменных. Как вы думаете, кто кроме вас **быстро** разберется зачем нужна переменная `P1`? Не экономьте на символах, исходный код пишется для человека и должен свободно читаться, условно говоря, сверху-вниз, да и IDE давно научились подсказывать полные имена по вводу первых символов.